# JavaFX как хранить пользователя в разных контроллерах?

Tags: javafx

Суть такая, в одном из контроллеров я совершаю авторизацию и перехожу на другую сцену, но там я не могу обращаться к пользователю которого создал в другом контроллере. Как это реализовать? Как передать авторизованного пользователя между контроллерами?

Comment: Можно создать синлтон App ("приложение"), в котором будут храниться общие данные приложения. Другие части приложения будут обращаться к App, и получать одни и те же данные.

Comment: Поддерживаю, в вашем случае самое простое использовать синглтон, какой-нибудь SessionManager класс

Answer (score 0):

Передачу пользователя я организовал следующим образом:

1. создал класс самого пользователя
2. в каждом контроллере создал переменную класса пользователя
3. создал метод в этих контроллерах, или можно, думаю, создать конструктор с инициализацией объекта юзер
4. при переходе к другому контроллеру я создаю объект нового контроллера и передаю ему объект пользователя